# Can I load incoming change sets without deleting sandbox in RTC

Tags: jenkins-plugins, rtc, rational-team-concert

I have a stream with 40GB of data. Every time I am deleting the sandbox, accepting changesets and loading the sandbox.
Loading whole data is taking longer.

Is there anyway to accept the changesets without deleting sandbox and to build that, through Jenkins.

Do we have RTC plugin for Jenkins that loads sandbox in incremental manner (by accepting&loading only delta changesets).

Answer (score 1):

The Job configuration of that [Jenkins RTC plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Team+Concert+Plugin#TeamConcertPlugin-JobConfiguration) does include an option:

> - "**Delete directory before loading.**"

and:

> - "**Accept latest changes before loading**": When loading the jenkins build workspace from a RTC repository workspace, there is an option to configure whether to accept latest changes before loading. By default, this option is selected.

[image: https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/66847632/jenkins_configure_job_1200_11.png?version=1&modificationDate=1461332037000&api=v2]

Check if, in your case, that option is selected or not.

Comment: Problem with this is, once you do a build, repository will go out of sync or metadata corrupts etc. isn't it the case ?

Comment: @RasDama Each build can checkout a fresh copy of the repo, rebuilding from scratch, avoiding any sync or metadata corruption issue.